# Why is Multimap not writing all values at one index to a text file?

Tags: c++, c++14, multimap

I am simply trying to write data from multimap to a text file in C++. My multimap contains two values at one key, although it outputs both values on the console, but it writes the key and value of the first one only in the file (means it writes only "a" and "100"). Why isn't it writing both values to File?
This is my code

```
int main() {

    multimap<string, string> rec;
    rec.insert({"a", "100"});
    rec.insert({"a", "200"});
    writeFile("a", rec);

}


void writeFile(string a, multimap<string, string> rec) {
    ofstream data;

    for (auto i = rec.find("a"); i != rec.end(); i++) {

data.open("file4.txt");

data << i->first << '\t' << i->second << '\n';

    }

}
```

Comment: Move `data.open("file4.txt");` out of for loop

Comment: `multimap::find` finds **an** element that matches the key, not necessarily the first one.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and then overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ofstream data; ... data.open("file4.txt");` to `ofstream data("file4.txt");`.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that you have put `data.open("file4.txt");` inside the for loop and so it overwrite the old value with the new one.
To solve this bring it outside the loop.

```
void writeFile(string a, multimap<string, string> rec) {
//----------------vvvvvvvvvvv------>use here outside for loop
    ofstream data("file4.txt");
    
    for (auto i = rec.find("a"); i != rec.end(); i++) 
    {
        data << i->first << '\t' << i->second << '\n';

    }
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/FDLJjIG1n)

Or

```
void writeFile(string a, multimap<string, string> rec) {
    ofstream data;
    
    data.open("file4.txt"); //this is now outside for loop
    for (auto i = rec.find("a"); i != rec.end(); i++) 
    {
        data << i->first << '\t' << i->second << '\n';

    }
    
}
```

Comment: [Useful reading?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417323/10871073)

Comment: It now looks decidedly 'odd' that you have both answered and voted to close this question. Stack Overflow is a repository of (useful) information, not really a race to get reputation.

Comment: I thought you were saying that since this was cause due to typo, this should be closed? Thus after seeing your first comment where you provided the link, i also voted to close.

Comment: That *is* what I was saying. You appear to have agreed, so why leave the answer? It's a good answer, of itself, but makes it harder for site curators to "clean up" posts that are unlikely to be of any long-term value.